# Finding the Expectation of a random varialble.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable and consider $Y=X$ with probability $.6$ and $Y=0$ with probability $.4$. Then what I understand for the expectation of $Y$ is $E[Y]=.6*X+.4*0=.6X$. But $E[Y]$ should be a fixed number and $.6*X$ is not. I am not sure what is going on here. How do we fix $E[Y]$?

Comment: What you have found is the conditional distribution $\mathbb{E}[Y~|X]$. To find the expectation of $Y$, you can take the expectation of this conditional distribution ($0.6X$) over the probability density of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it concrete. You toss a coin with probability $0.6$ of landing heads. If it does, you get to toss a fair die, and get in dollars whatever it shows. If the coin lands tails you  get nothing.

Let $Y$ be the amount you get. We want to find $E(Y)$.
If $X$ is the number that shows on the die. then we have a situation exactly like the one described.

It is presumably clear that in this gambling situation, $E(Y)$ is a specific number, and that indeed $E(Y)=(0.6)(3.5)=(0.6)E(X)$.

Comment: Of course, your explanations make a lot of sense. But what I am trying is to develop a more theoretical answer. What about the following arguments?

Let $I=1$ with probability $.6$ and $I=0$ with probability $.4$, then $Y=XI$ and $E[Y]=E[XI]=E[E[XI|I]]=.6E[X]+.4E[0]=.6E[X]$?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. You should give it  as an answer, and after a while accept it.